# How can I create a 2d array of a list of company teams and names so I can loop through it?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, multidimensional-array

I have this spreadsheet filled with some information about each employee that I have to migrate to a different spreadsheets. Each spreadsheet will include a different mixture of employee names and info depending on which team I'm working on.

The team info goes like this:

Team 1 - 5 names

Team 2 - 3 names

Team 3 - 7 names

.

.

.

I have about 20 teams I need to work on.

I think I've figured out how to use for and if loops to get the info I need and to copy those rows to a new spreadsheet. I'm doing this by finding the cell that matches the "employee name" in my array and then I copy the info in that row.

The problem I'm having is how to create a 2d array that stores all the names so I can loop through them (especially since the rows are not the same length).

Does anyone know how to do this?? Thank you!

Comment: Use an object: `{ team1: [ array of name ], team2: [ array of names] }` etc.

Comment: When you utilize getValues() in the current spreadsheet you will have all of the data in the sheet in an array of arrays.  At this point you may use the map methold of arrays to create several different arrays which can then be stored in several different sheets utilizing setValues();  Without a specific view of your spreadsheet and more details it's hard to provide any more specific information.

Answer (score 0):

Easy

```
var teamOne = ["names","names","names","names"];
var teamTwo = ["names2","names2","names2","names2"];
var teamThree = ["names3","names3","names3","names3"];

var teams = [teamOne ,teamTwo ,teamTheree];
```

and then loop teams

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating an object where team names are keys and team members are values.

```
const company = {
  team1: ["name", "name2", "name3"],
  team2: ["name4", "name7"],
  team1: ["name5", "name8", "name6"]
}
```

Then you can use combinations of `Object.prototype.keys` and/or  `Object.prototype.values` as needed

Answer (score 0):

**Loading Different Destination Sheets from a Single Source Sheet**

> Using different data sets for each destination sheet.

```
function differentliststodifferentsheets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const svs = ssh.getRange(1, 1, ssh.getLastRow(), ssh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const sh123 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  sh123.clear();
  const sh145 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  sh145.clear();
  let vs123 = [];
  let vs145 = [];
  svs.forEach((r, i) => {
    vs123.push([r[0],r[1],r[2]]);
    vs145.push([r[0],r[3],r[4]]);
  });
  sh123.getRange(1,1,vs123.length,vs123[0].length).setValues(vs123);
  sh145.getRange(1,1,vs145.length,vs145[0].length).setValues(vs145);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs123));
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs145));
}
```

Sheet1:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1,1 | 1,2 | 1,3 | 1,4 | 1,5 |
| 2,1 | 2,2 | 2,3 | 2,4 | 2,5 |
| 3,1 | 3,2 | 3,3 | 3,4 | 3,5 |
| 4,1 | 4,2 | 4,3 | 4,4 | 4,5 |
| 5,1 | 5,2 | 5,3 | 5,4 | 5,5 |
| 6,1 | 6,2 | 6,3 | 6,4 | 6,5 |
| 7,1 | 7,2 | 7,3 | 7,4 | 7,5 |
| 8,1 | 8,2 | 8,3 | 8,4 | 8,5 |
| 9,1 | 9,2 | 9,3 | 9,4 | 9,5 |
| 10,1 | 10,2 | 10,3 | 10,4 | 10,5 |

Sheet2:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1,1 | 1,2 | 1,3 |
| 2,1 | 2,2 | 2,3 |
| 3,1 | 3,2 | 3,3 |
| 4,1 | 4,2 | 4,3 |
| 5,1 | 5,2 | 5,3 |
| 6,1 | 6,2 | 6,3 |
| 7,1 | 7,2 | 7,3 |
| 8,1 | 8,2 | 8,3 |
| 9,1 | 9,2 | 9,3 |
| 10,1 | 10,2 | 10,3 |

Sheet3:

| COL1 | COL4 | COL5 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1,1 | 1,4 | 1,5 |
| 2,1 | 2,4 | 2,5 |
| 3,1 | 3,4 | 3,5 |
| 4,1 | 4,4 | 4,5 |
| 5,1 | 5,4 | 5,5 |
| 6,1 | 6,4 | 6,5 |
| 7,1 | 7,4 | 7,5 |
| 8,1 | 8,4 | 8,5 |
| 9,1 | 9,4 | 9,5 |
| 10,1 | 10,4 | 10,5 |